# Rebind Ember View after JQuery replacing the element

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have an Ember View that loads a plugin in the `didInsertElement()` hook. The plugin replaces the view element with it's own element. The element retains it's Ember id but seems to lose the bound event handlers.

Is it possible to rebind the View to the new element to retain the event handling functionality?

**This is what I am trying:**

```
App.MyView = App.AbstractView.extend({

  tagName: 'canvas',

  // plugin loading goes here because this.element
  // does not yet exist in init(), and the plugin 
  // needs an id
  didInsertElement: function() {

    // load jquery plugin. this plugin replaces the root
    // element of this view, leaving the id intact
    loadPlugin(this.get('element').id);

    var that = this;

    // rebind click
    $(this.get('element')).click(function(e){
      that.click(e);
    });
  },

  // doesn't work...
  click: function(evt) {
    alert("test");
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are attempting might be possible, but you are better off applying the plugin to a sub-element of the view. This will preserve the separation of jQuery and Ember, reducing your code's dependency on the implementation details of either framework.

For completion's sake:

**Template:**

```
<div class="replace-me"></div>
```

**View:**

```
App.MyView = App.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    // use handy local jQuery selector
    this.$('.replace-me').myJQueryPlugin();
  },

  click: function(event) {
    // smooth sailing as usual
  }
});
```